# SSL_ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR_ALERT when accessing api platform

Tags: api-platform.com

API Platform V.2.6.5 with docker-compose downloaded from the official website

Problem : I can't send requests to the API, or access the UI from my browser. I'm facing a **SSL_ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR_ALERT**

This is a brand new project I did not edit any file.

Note that i'm using Docker Toolbox for Windows and my docker is running on https://192.168.100.0, not localhost.

I tried on anoter PC where the domain for docker is localhost and it works.

However, the containers start well. I can even create entities and update my database.

Do you have an idea why this error is happening and how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's a caddy thing not having a valid SSL certificate, check at

```
docker-compose logs caddy
```

Here is an issue at caddy community: https://caddy.community/t/local-ip-address-creates-ssl-error/11314